# compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4' на android 4.4.4

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему при добавлении в gradle - 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
приложение на андроид 4.4.4 начинает сразу вылетать при запуске? 
Пишет My Application ... has stopped.
На андроид 5 все нормально, хотя Gapps везде установлены..

Comment: Попробуйте implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4' , sdk нужно добавить play service

Comment: Студия 2.3.3, там вместо implementation - compile. Может просто с андроидом 4 это не совместимо? У меня на планшете тоже сразу вылетает приложение, если я установлю 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'

Comment: Покажите `logcat` хотя бы.

Comment: я знаю этот баг именно для 4.4, просто используйте библиотеку ниже, например 10.0